# How to turn off the backlight of the Apple logo on top of MacBook?

Tags: fedora, macbook

I'm running Fedora 19 Linux on MacBook Pro and power management is critical to me. I wondering if I can turn off the backlight of the big Apple logo to save little energy with battery only. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  It's not a software thing.  This is powered by your display so if the display is up and powered on, the light will be on.

Sorry mate!

Comment: It seems correct because the backlight varies when I adjust the brightness of screen. Is there any lower level configuration below OS to make it?

Comment: The thing is, the same lamp that's providing backlight is lighting the icon.

Comment: @shawnzhu it doesn't actually use any more energy. It's just allowing some of the light to go out the back. There's no extra light.

Comment: I found [this question](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/switcher-hangout/106971-how-turn-off-apple-light-back-display.html) from Mac Forum as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you covered the logo with aluminum foil, in theory it would reflect some of the light back into the display, allowing you to run a microscopically lower backlight setting with the same display brightness.